# Missing first html tag in jquery-tmpl

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

I am trying to build a table row using `jQuery-tmpl` [plugin](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl).
These are the values for each cell of the row:

```
var fields = ["a","b","c"];
```

Here is my template:

```
<tr>
    <td>{{= $data}}</td>
</tr>
```

**The problem** is that the template generated is:

```
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td>
```

But the **expected result** is:

```
<tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
</tr>
```

The only way I have found to resolve this problem is to add the `tr` tag in the javascript, like so:

```
$("<tr>"+htmlGeneratedByTemplate+"</tr>").appendTo("#id-of-my-table");
```

Does anyone have the same problem?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use `appendTo` to add the list inside `tr`

```
<tr id="myList"></tr>

 $.tmpl( "myTemplate", movies ).appendTo( "#myList" );
```

Comment: I have updated my question. "#id" is actually the id of my table. I am appending the new row to this table, so the row doesn't exist...